# is there any better code so we can't use condition for universal App

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

i want common way of this in below code i used this code for ipad and iphone i don't want to use this Condition can anyone help me that i can't use this condition i want common code .. thanks in advance '

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
   newSize = CGSizeMake(440.0, 440.0);

    if (self.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width == 440.0) {

       newSize.width = 786.0;

       newSize.height = 590.0; 
    }
}
else    
{
   newSize = CGSizeMake(190.0, 190.0); 
   if (self.thumbnailImageView.frame.size.width == 190.0) {

      newSize.width = 320.0;

      newSize.height = 340.0;

  }
}
```

Comment: Better option is to use AutoLayouts..!Have u tried using it.

Comment: no it's runtime code..

Comment: what are about iPhone 6 plus?

Comment: Use XIB file instead

Comment: Use constraints, autoresizingMasks, and calculated sizes based on parent view sizes.

Comment: @rmaddy any example that i will study ?

Comment: Yes this condition contains lot of Duplication code can anyone have good idea for this?

Comment: As per rmaddy's comment Autolayout constraints or autoresizing is better idea.

Comment: yes autolayout is better idea but how can we do in runtime code like above code ? it's for TapGesture right ? so after double click it show's particular size

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS 8, I would recommend you take a look at the new size classes paradigm recently introduced. It abstracts out screen size and idiom and allows you to build view controllers that render correctly on iPhone or iPad, not depending on the device, but the size of the view.

For example, if you have a narrow list view that is displayed full screen on the iPhone, it can also be displayed in a popover or master (in master/detail) on the iPad. By defining the size class for the view controller, it will be displayed correctly on any device (including the iPhone 6 Plus, in landscape).

I recommend you watch the WWDC 2014 video on "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit" for a more detailed explanation.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#216

Comment: And even though this has been said, I would recommend using AutoLayout. Constraint constant can be changed, old constraints can be removed and new constraints added at runtime. It provides a much more descriptive way of designing your UI and is much more extensible given the various screen sizes now available.

Comment: is it anyway for iOS7?

Comment: Nope, this one is iOS 8 only